# How to pass the thrown Exception to a custom error view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

There are a lot of good posts about how to set up custom error pages in ASP.NET MVC, but couldn't find one yet which would describe if it's possible to pass the Exception object itself, for example to show the exception message (for user errors).

I've set up an ErrorController with actions and views like NotFound, BadReqest and a catch-all Error. I would like to print out the exception message (if present) for example in the BadReqest view (I use 500 status for user errors as well).

Is it possible? I'm using IIS7.5 and ASP.NET MVC5.

UPDATE

Here is a sample scenario. A request is being sent to `Account/Users`. Let's say it requires some special privilege which I check in the action, and if not met, I throw an appropriate exception with text `"You don't have permission to see the list of users."`. In effect of this exception my custom error action gets invoked by the custom errors module, but I have no idea what the base exception was (if any). I would like to be able to check which exception was thrown (if any) in my ErrorController, and include its message in the error page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just can Create one `PageLayout` for all Errors, and pass Error text (`Exception message`) from controller to page in `ViewBag`

Update:

You can pass Exception in
Session,Cookie,TempData

Comment: Thank you, but passing between Cotnroller and View is not problem (I would prefer a strongly typed View with Exception type anyway), but the problem is how the Excetion could be retrieved in the ErrorController.BadReqest action for example.

Comment: You can pass Exception in Session,Cookie,TempData

Comment: Maybe you just need create Table in database with all Exception text, and check with ID(from DB) which module you need